# effective way to solve isomorphism of groups

Tags: group-theory

Hello I am studying group isomorphisms but I fail to check in a few cases whether two groups are isomorphic or not.for example in $S_3 \times Z_4 $ and $ S_4$
I have checked with cardinality,commutative,cyclic properties but not working here.Please give some way .

Comment: What's the centre of the two groups respectively?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Isomorphic groups have the same 'group' properties. A few useful examples
of such properties of a group $G$:

1. $G$ is abelian (then any isomorphic group is also abelian)
2. There is $g\in G$ of order $|g|$ (then any isomorphic group also
   have an element of order $|g|$)
3. The order of $G$ is $|G|$ (then any isomorphic group also have
   order $|G|$)
4. There is a subgroup $H$ of $G$ of order $|H|$ and which
   is isomorphic to a group $K$ (complete the corresponding property)

In your case I suggest to argue that one group have an element of order $12$ and the other does not.

Comment: Please elaborate how did u get that easily & since it is not always possible to argue like that is there any shortcut to help me out in a competitive exam

Comment: @learningmaths - How did I get to the element of order $12$ ? with one elements of orders $3,4$ in the cross product and using $gcd(3,4)=1$ so their multiplication is of order $12$. I used the cycles decomposition and the fact that the lcm of their lengths is the order of permutation to deduce there isn't an element of order $12$ in $S_4$